# Getting Incorrect Access Token Type from WSO2 RESTClient

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm evaluating WSO2 API Manager 1.3.0 and have it deployed on a Linux server.
I've published an API, then as a client user, I've subscribed to that API
and also generated production keys for it.

```
 Access Token       EnhC3kxAf6hL68pqMSr2gYwK950a
 Consumer Key       TyEqcYa4hytVPhpiQqRWVNiVIZ0a
 Consumer Secret    7VC9z347ZIzf_K_15rjsGyXcRIYa
```

When I try to access the API through RESTClient and pass in the Access Token for authentication as per http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Subscribing+to+an+API and http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM120/Testing+an+API :

```
Authorization:Bearer EnhC3kxAf6hL68pqMSr2gYwK950a
```

I get an error

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900905</ams:code>
  <ams:message>Incorrect Access Token Type is provided</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Access failure for API: /test, version: 1 with key: EnhC3kxAf6hL68pqMSr2gYwK950a</ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your REST command ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the API from publisher app,the last input field section is to enter 'API Resources' details.There you can set different three types of authorization levels for each resource verb per url pattern as;

1.None- No authorization header required to invoke particular API

2.Application-Application Access Token[The access token generated per application in Store app] required to invoke the API

3.Application User -End user access token[which can be generated from loginAPI by using generated consumer key/secret per application in Store] required to invoke the API

If you are going to try to invoke a particular API resource url,first you need to make sure you are trying with the correct authorization scheme.For example if you set your accessing API resource verb authorization scheme as 'Application User' and if you try invoking that resource verb with Application Access Token,similar error which you have get will be thrown.

As per your given info,you have tried with the API with Application Access Token. Can you double check,by going to Publisher app->Browse the related API->Navigate to edit API page ,whether you have set the authentication scheme for your accessing resource url method as 'Application'. ?

Thanks;

/Lalaji

Comment: Each of my resources are using the default auth, 'Application'.

Comment: Hi,Sorry for the late reply.Just wanted to know one more info.Are you trying to invoke the API with the same URL showing in the APIStore view for your created API,without appending any query parameters or more url string parts? If yes..then can u check whether your trying API url is end with "/".If not,please try adding "/" to end of your trying API url and check.It'll work.This needs to add as you have defined the API resource url pattern as '/*' or '/xxxx'.However the shown error needs to be corrected [wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-943] and we will fix this issue with our next release.

Comment: I am only able to get this to work by setting the Auth to none.

Comment: I tried instructions on http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/User+Tokens and http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Quick+Start+Guide and neither worked.

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Subscribing+to+an+API says "Before deploying the API manager to users, extend the default expiration time by editing the <AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod> tag in file <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/identity.xml." I changed that to 100 days, restarted WSO2, recreated my app, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue - the production url was configured like http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/services/rest/entity.json/search with a context /search, URL prefix as search/1.0.0 and URL pattern as /*.  - on executing /search/1.0.0/abc on the REST client, I have got the same error.

The error was fixed on setting the production url as http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/services/rest with a context as /search. While adding the API resources, set URL prefix as /search/1.0.0 and URL pattern as /entity.json/search/*.